# Django REST framework is changing object values when request method is GET

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i have problem with (not wanted) objects values setting. I have viewset where serialiser is chosen by request.method. I want to update DateTimeField only WITH POST/PUT method, and then can check this value with GET method but.. after posting new object I got json like this

```
{
    "datetimefield": "2021-10-26 23:01:53.272194"
}
```

and after GET method I got this (for the same object):

```
{
    "datetimefield": ""
}
```

my code:

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if (self.request.method == 'POST'):
            return FirstSerializer
        else:
            return SecondAppSerializer

class FirstSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    datetimefield = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_datetimefield(self, obj):
        return str(datetime.today())

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('datetimefield')

class SecondSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeObject
        fields = ('datetimefield')

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    datetimefield  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `SerializerMethodField` as a calculated read-only field, so the output that you got from POST is just generated by `get_datetimefield` and never really saved to the database. That's why you get an empty data on GET.

To solve this, you can remove the `datetimefield` field from the serializer, and let `save` handle it by overriding `perform_create`:

```py
class FirstSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # remove datetimefield
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('some_other_fields...')


class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(datetimefield=str(datetime.today()))
```

Or if possible, I highly recommend to just change the model field to [**`DateTimeField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) with [**`auto_now_add`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) set to `True`.

In this approach, there is no need to manage `datetimefield` on the view or serializer. The model will automatically handle it for you when a new object is created. So:

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    datetimefield  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```